# Search number of elements in List by time

Tags: java, android

I have list of objects. Object has fields: name, surname and time(in long). I want to check how many items from this list have the same hour. I convert long to HH:mm and now I need to know for exampole how many items have time 0, how many time have time 1 etc. Something like this:

```
hours - number of elements
0     - 10
1     - 2
2     - 4
...
23    - 13
etc until get all day hours.
```

Any idea how can I simply achieve this idea

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Person> people;
int[] count = new int[24];

for(Person p : people) {
    count[hourOf(p.time)]++;
}
```

Not sure how you have the time stored (i.e. what the long represents), but if you have `HH:mm` as a `String`, then you can compute the hour easily:

```
int hourOf(String hhmm) {
    return Integer.parseInt(hhmm.substring(0, hhmm.indexOf(':')));
}
```

where `hhmm.indexOf(':')` can be replaced by `2` if all hours are `0` padded.